# Prove that $(a^6+b^6-1)(a^6+b^6-2)$ is divisible by $252$ if $a$ and $b$ are coprime integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Prove that $(a^6+b^6-1)(a^6+b^6-2)$ is divisible by $252$ if $a$ and $b$ are coprime integers.
I thought about proving that this number is divisible by $2$, $3$ and $7$ but I don't know how should I do that.

Comment: Well, please show the own effort, this is the way it works. You have the product of two consecutive numbers. Any immediate idea from here?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. As already noted in the previous comment, show what you have done and where this comes from: An exercise in a book? In a class? Your own conjecture? A statement in an article or textbook?

Comment: $252 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 7$, no factor of $11$ there, so I fail to see why it is relevant  that the expression might not (I haven't checked) be divisible by $11$.

Comment: It seems like it might be divisible by $504=2\cdot 252,$ and even stronger result.

Comment: You're on the right track, but divisibility by a positive integer is equivalent to divisibility by each of the prime _powers_ that appears in its prime factorization - in this case, $4$ (or $8$ to prove @ThomasAndrews's conjecture), $7$ & $9$.

Comment: Do you know [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)?

Answer (score 0):

Put $E=(a^6+b^6-1)(a^6+b^6-2)$; the two factors are consecutive so coprime and $252=2^2\cdot3^2\cdot7$.

$1)$ $E\equiv0\pmod7$. By Fermat's Little Theorem it is quite clear,  even if $a$ or $b$ is divisible by $7$.

$2)$ $E\equiv0\pmod{3^2}$. We know that $$(X\pm1)^6=X^6\pm6X^5+15X^4\pm20X^3+15X^2\pm6X+1$$ There are two cases to consider:

$► (a,b)=(3m,3n\pm1)\Rightarrow(3m)^6+(3n\pm1)^6-1\equiv\pm6(3n)\equiv0\pmod{3^2}$.

$► (a,b)=(3m\pm1,3n\pm1)\Rightarrow(3m\pm1)^6+(3n\pm1)^6-2\equiv\pm6(3m)\pm6(3n)\equiv0\pmod{3^2}$.

$3) E\equiv0\pmod{2^2}$. There are two cases to consider:

$► (a,b)=(2m,2n+1)\Rightarrow(2m)^6+(2n+1)^6-1\equiv6(2n)\equiv0\pmod4.$

$►(a,b)=(2m+1,2n+1)\Rightarrow(2m+1)^6+(2n+1)^6-2\equiv6(2m+2n)\equiv0\pmod4$.

(*In both, $2)$ and $3)$,we have used one of the two factors of $E$ to prove the divisibility*).

Comment: You can use Euler's Theorem also to do cases 2) and 3). E.g. either $\gcd(a,9) =1 = \gcd(b.9)$, in which case $a^6 + b^6 \equiv 2 \mod 9$. Or  wlog $\gcd(a,9) >1 = \gcd(b.9)$  in which case $a^6 \equiv 0 \mod 9$ and $b^6 \equiv 1 \mod 9$.